# Embedding Youtube Videos with a Specific Time Stamp

Tags: media9, multimedia

I use something like this to embed youtube videos:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
    %\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/<video id>?rel=0}   % Flash file
\end{document}
```

I would like to link to a video at a specific time.  Usually the time is appended to the url as something link `#t=144` for example.  This of course leads to the following error at compile time:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

I tried to escape the # with `\#` but no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: Why `#`? The standard is `&`, as already shown in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` in Youtube URLs is wrong. The syntax is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Selecting_Content_to_Play).

Youtube clips are configured using Flash variables. These can be appended to the URL or added to the `flashvars` option argument. In either case, FlashVars are separated using the ampersand `&`, as already demonstrated in the cited example.

Thus, to start into the clip at a particular time, one needs to say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
   &start=144
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/GZ9e3Dy7obA?rel=0}% Flash file

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/GZ9e3Dy7obA?rel=0&start=144}% Flash file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice!  I chose this as my solution as it avoids using both `#` and `&`

Answer (score 4):

First, you could change the catcode of `#` to use it like a normal character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
    %\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

{\catcode`\#=12
\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/<video id>?rel=0#t=144}% Flash file
}
\end{document}
```

This is just to answer your question about `#`.

**BUT** according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379268/youtube-droped-t-start-time-support-in-direct-url-and-embed-videos the syntax for specifying a start time has changed.

So, for your application, use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
    %\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/<video id>?start=144}% Flash file

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\#` works for me (at least it makes it into the URL in the PDF output), the catcode change is not necessary. Nonetheless, `#` is wrong in Youtube URLs and has no effect.